# Customising hg log output

Tags: mercurial

(Mercurial newbie)

I'm trying to get hg log to give me the full changeset description, but without the file listing given by the -v option. Basically, I want the default output but with the full description rather than just the first line.

I've played about with templates, but can't see a way to do what seems like it should be a very simple change. Am I missing a built-in solution?

Comment: See [`hg help templates`](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#templates) for information about the template keywords.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`hg log --template ...` or `... --style ...`

with hand-made template or style.

Just write it

PS: Hint - use {desc} keyword

Comment: Thanks, I was trying that but as far as I can see, {desc} only gives you the first line.

Comment: @TimH: The `{desc}` field returns the entire commit message, not just the first line.  For it to only return the first line, it would need to be run through the `{desc|firstline}` filter.

Comment: Apologies; you're both right, of course! Not sure what I did wrong before, but {desc} is doing just what you said. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you want is built in, but the log is formatted so:

Powershell:

```
hg log -v | where {$_ -notmatch "files:"}
```

*Nix:

```
hg log -v | grep -v "files:"
```

achieves what you want I think.

Comment: Thanks, that does the job. Though I would like to find a way of doing it through a template if possible (and not too involved!).

Comment: It is built in. See Lazy Bager's comment.