# Change default `hg log` template?

Tags: mercurial

Is it possible to change the template that `hg log` uses by default? I would like to derive a such template that would look like the default but would use `mailmap` function to show commit author instead of the original recorded author.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343632/customising-hg-log-output

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that via the `[alias]` section in an applicable **.hgrc** file. So if you know how to create an appropriate template, it's easy (I don't know what mailmap output looks like, so this here is just an example how to tackle it in .hgrc):

```
[alias]
log = log --template="{date|isodate} {author}\n\t{desc|tabindent}\n\n"
```

The main issue would be where to get the committer info from - a property mercurial doesn't record by default (that is *author* and *committer* are the same). Probably there do exist extensions which allow that distinction - do you happen to use one?

Additionally: I would recommend to NOT overwrite a default command output, but to define a new command like

```
[alias]
mlog = (whatever you need here)
```